# Create SQL Script Repository

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need to get all my SQL scripts in some kind of script repository. I have searched the web but no luck so far. I thought of creating a repository in a SQL database, my problem so far is to properly manage versioning of the scripts.

We are using to many scripts and everyone is using a different version of a script and is causing skewed data outputs. Has anyone successfully created something like this or is there a free application that can do this?

Comment: You might want to look at something like [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) (not free...) or placing scripts inside TFS or SVN yourselves

Comment: If your organization is already using TFS (Team Foundation Services) then follow Mark's suggestion to check in the scripts.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a way to create SQL Scripts Repository.
Add new template folder
[image]

Add script files 
[image]

Comment: This is nice, but would not allow for version control of the scripts or centralized distribution.

Comment: For version control and centralized code distribution we were using VSS but now moved on Team Foundation Server (TFS)

Answer (score 0):

I've used both [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/) and [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) in the past (both free), and I think [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/) has some tools that integrate into SSMS.

Comment: I am investigating GIT, Our organization already uses GIT for software.